# Uninitialized constant when using AjaxDatatablesRails::Extensions

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I follow the guide from [Ajax datatables rails repo](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails) but when my app send request to server, it throw me this error

```
NameError (uninitialized constant AjaxDatatablesRails::Extensions)
```

And the line cause error is this include line

```
class BookDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base
  include AjaxDatatablesRails::Extensions::Kaminari
```

Current using ajax-datables-rails 0.4.0

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From ajax-datatables-rails README.md

[ajax-datatables-rails](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails)

The core has been rewriten to remove dependency on Kaminari or WillPaginate.

To migrate on the v0.4 you'll need to :

a. **update your DataTables classes to remove all the extend directives**

b. switch to hash definitions of view_columns

c. update your views to declare your columns bindings